# Visual Studio from command line generates warnings; IDE does not

Tags: c++, build, batch-file, visual-studio-2005

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 (32-bit) on a Windows XP system. I've got a C++ project that I build from the command line (in a batch file) that uses ***devenv.exe*** to launch the build. Here's an example of how it gets launched:

```
{path_to_devenv.exe} my_solution.sln /rebuild "Debug|Win32" /out my_logfile.txt
```

Within the code for this project, we use a few pragma statements to disable some extraneous warnings that we don't want to see:

```
#pragma warning ( disable : 4521 4522 )
// Some code here
#pragma warning ( default : 4521 4522 )
```

When the project is built in the **debug** configuration from the IDE, these warnings do not show up in the build output. When the same project is built from the command line, the warnings **do** show up in our log file (which we specified with the **/out** command line parameter). When building in release, the warnings do not show up in either case.

Is there something different about driving VS 2005 through devenv.exe that causes the pragma to be ignored in the debug case? Why should these warnings show up in one world and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly the only reason I can see this happening is when the pragmas aren't seen.

Check

- the build configuration (are you building `Debug|Win32` from within the IDE too?)
- and especially the include paths (are they the same; perhaps see whether the environment contains other settings)
- are you doing a ***full rebuild* from within the IDE**? I wouldn't rule out that you *usually* don't see the warnings in the IDE, because you *usually* do an incremental build and the related sources don't need to be built. Check whether you get the same errors when doing a full *rebuild* in the IDE

If you are desperate for clues, you can always keep the result of preprocessing using both variants and compare them. The 'keep preprocessed source' option is hidden somewhere under the 'Preprocessor' C++ build settings.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the tips.(1) I'm positive I'm building the same configuration in the IDE as on the command line. (2) The include paths are the same in both configurations (in fact, I diff'ed both configs to see what changed). (3) I am doing a full rebuild in both cases. The "keep preprocessed source" option was a help; both variants were the same. Now when I spin a build from the command line, I don't see the warnings. Maybe the log file was being appended to? Maybe it's intermittent? Either way, these tips were helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I just answered my own question. Our log file is being appended to. The warnings I was seeing were from old builds. I'm such an idiot!

Comment: Hola! Thanks for the feedback anyways.